# Regex to move answer feedback to before answers?

Tags: regex

I have some text questions for a question bank.  They need reformatting and I can't figure out the regex to move the feedback to between the question and the answer choices.  The feedback starts with an "@".  The * indicates the correct answer.  Originally the feedback was for only a correct answer, but our new LMS only supports general feedback for any incorrect answer.  How do I move the @ followed by the feedback text to before the first answer choice?

```
32) This is the question text.  This is the question text.  This is the question text.  This is the question text.  This is the question text.  This is the question text.  This is the question text.  This is the question text.  This is the question text.  This is the question text.  

*a. 091°.
@ (Chapter - Section)
This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  This is the feedback.  
b. 095°.
c. 099°.
```

Comment: What programming language/text editing tool are you using?

Comment: Using NotePad++ or Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using regex `^(\d+\).*\n\n)((?:\*?[a-z]\. .*\n)*)(@ .*\n.*\n)((?:\*?[a-z]\. .*\n)*)` and replacement string `$1$3\n$2$4`.

Here regex means:

- `^(\d+\).*\n\n)` line beginning with digits, closing bracket and space and followed by two new lines,
- `((?:\*?[a-z]\. .*\n)*)` line beginning with optional `*`, letter, dot and any number of any symbols repeated any number of times. Any number of answers.
- `(@ .*\n.*\n)` two lines, first beginning with `@` (feedback)
- `((?:\*?[a-z]\. .*\n)*)` same as before.

Demo of replacement can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/OljY1L/2). Also there you could tinker with replacement string, as you didn't provide enough input to reliable guess what output is expected.

To use this open your file with something like VScode or Sublime Text:
Open replacement view <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>
Make sure option `Use regular expression` is enabled.
Paste regex and replacement string.
Replace all <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Enter</kbd>

EDIT: To account multi-line feedback

```
^(\d+\).*\n+)((?:\*?[a-z]\. .*\n)*)(@ .*(?:\n.*)*?\n(?=[a-z]\.|\n\d+\)|\n\n))((?:\*?[a-z]\. .*\n)*)
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation/solution.  It almost works perfectly.It seems to fail if the feedback has blank lines between paragraphs since each paragraph is a single line of text.  Is there a way to specify 1 or more line breaks at the end of a sentence?

Comment: @user2112819, I've added attempt for multi-line feedback, but no guaranties, since you haven't provided sample.

Comment: By the way, best way to provide sample would be open link to regex from answer, paste your sample data, click `Update Regex` and share generated link.

Comment: @JuJuBee, seems like my updated regex should work.

Comment: @JuJuBee, You haven't updated regex form my edit. [Updated regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OljY1L/6)

Comment: Try again... I dumped actual data in this time... https://regex101.com/r/OljY1L/8

Comment: @JuJuBee, corrected. There was also a problem in varying number of newlines. Corrected demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/OljY1L/9). Notice, for this regex correctly parse last question, I've added couple of new-lines ant the end.

Comment: YOU ROCK!  Thank you sooooooo much.  I have over 100 files to edit and the thought of doing it by hand was a nightmare.